# AWS Load Balancer times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I created a classic loadbalancer on AWS with two EC2 instances running a simple flask application.

[image]

The security group on the ELB is set to allow all inbound/outbound. The security groups for the EC2 instances are set to HTTP 0.0.0.0/0 port 5000. The health of instances is good - I can see that in the ELB dashboard and also can see the 200 ping responses from my applications in debug. I can access the webapplications directly when using the EC2's ip addresses with no problem. However, when using ELB's public DSN, the request times out:

[image]

This timeout occurs even if the applications are not running. So I assume that the problem is at the front end (with ELB). I have gone through tons of aws troubleshoot suggestions (which are not very straightforward for me as a starter) but did not manage to get it working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Security Group allowing all traffic from all sources]Check your ELB's security group that it's allowing 0.0.0.0/0 to access port 80.

You say 'set to default' but by default there are no inbound rules on a security group.

Comment: Yes, firewalls are set "All traffic" - I assume that covers 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: "All traffic" just means all protocols/ports, the source still needs to be set to allow traffic from all IPs.  Added image to illustrate.

Comment: Yep, explicitly specifying the rules solved the problem. Thank you.